# Field History prior to enabling History Tracking

Tags: history-tracking, field-history, closedate

*'Salesforce starts tracking field history from the date and time that you enable it on a field. Changes made before this date and time aren’t included and didn’t create an entry in the History related list. '*

I just enabled history tracking on the 'Close Date' field on Opportunity. Can we retrieve field history prior to enabling via API or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. There's just no data recorded in the first place prior to enabling history tracking on the field.

Comment: Note, however, that [Opportunity History Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_opp_history.htm&type=5) records the value for that field at the first of every month, so there is still some historical data available, just not down to the minute that you get with Field History.